# Shell script : changing working dir and spaces in folder name

Tags: bash, shell

I want to make a script that takes a file path for argument, and cds into its folder.
Here is what I made :

```
#!/bin/bash

#remove the file name, and change every space into \space
shorter=`echo "$1" | sed 's/\/[^\/]*$//' | sed 's/\ /\\\ /g'`

echo $shorter
cd $shorter
```

I actually have 2 questions (I am a relative newbie to shell scripts) :

- How could I make the cd "persistent" ? I want to put this script into /usr/bin, and then call it from wherever in the filesystem. Upon return of the script, I want to stay in the `$shorter` folder. Basically, if pwd was /usr/bin, I could make it by typing `. script /my/path` instead of `./script /my/path`, but what if I am in an other folder ?
- The second question is trickier. My script fails whenever there is a space in the given argument. Although `$shorter` is exactly what I want (for instance `/home/jack/my\ folder/subfolder`), cd fails whith the error `/usr/bin/script : line 4 : cd: /home/jack/my\: no file or folder of this type`. I think I have tried everything, using things like `cd '$shorter'` or `cd "'"$shorter"'"` doesn't help. What am I missing ??

Thanks a lot for your answers

Comment: If you are using a whole file path as an argument... why not just use the built-in `cd /path/to/file`?

Comment: Regarding the space, add double quotes: `cd "$shorter"`.

Comment: Well, I'd have loved it if it worked, but here is what I have : `bash: cd: /home/jack/Images/P1220527.JPG: Is not a folder`. And since `man cd` doesn't exist, I don't think any --option could make it work... Does that actually work on your computer ? What distro do you use ?

Comment: I think I already tried the double quotes. I tried it again though. It still doesn't work, but it is slightly different : I have `/usr/bin/script: line 4 : cd: /home/jack/this\ is\ a\ space: No file or folder of this type`. It does take the full path into account now, but still fails on the space...

Comment: Just for some clarification... what I meant by my comment earlier was: this script seems to just re-implement what the normal `cd` command does.  Is the script just for practice?

Comment: No, I'm lazy, and being from the Mac world, I love drag n drop. I wanted to cd easily into a folder by dragging a file from this folder into the console. And unfortunately, cd /this/is/some/file doesn't cd into some/... But oHessling just gave me a perfect answer. Thanks a lot to all of you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `.bashrc` add the following line:

```
function shorter() { cd "${1%/*}"; }
```

- `%` means remove the smaller pattern from the end
- `/*` is the patern

Then in your terminal:

```
$ . ~/.bashrc   # to refresh your bash configuration
$ type shorter  # to check if your new function is available
shorter is a function
shorter () 
{ 
    cd "${1%/*}"
}
$ shorter ./your/directory/filename  # this will move to ./your/directory
```

Comment: Not sure why someone would downvote this: I think it looks like a succinct, correct answer … comment?

Comment: Wow, two answers in one single code line ! Thanks a million, exactly what I wanted to do :-)

Comment: I upvoted (but I cannot upvote twice, so it stays back at 0...)

Comment: Thank you guys @Jaypal. When I went to sleep yesterday my answer was -1 and I was disappointed. This morning I discover a positive vote and validated answer. I am so happy. Happy Week-End to everybody ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, there is no need for the `shorter` variable at all. You can just do:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "${1%/*}"
```

#### Explanation

Most shells, including `bash`, have what is called *Parameter Expansion* and they are very powerful and efficient as they allow you to manipulate variables nativly within the shell that would normally require a call to an external binary.

Two common examples of where you can use Parameter Expansion over an external call would be:

```
${var%/*} # replaces dirname
${var##*/} # replaces basename
```

See this FAQ on [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) to learn more. In fact, while you're there might as well go over the whole FAQ

Comment: Wow ! As simple as that ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: But what does "${1%/*}" actually do/mean ??

Answer (score 1):

The first part:

- The change of directory *won't* be “persistent” beyond the lifetime of your script, because your script runs in a new shell process. You could, however, use a shell alias or a shell function. For example, you could embed the code in a shell function and define it in your `.bash_profile` or other source location.

  ```
  mycdfunction () {
       cd /blah/foo/"$1"
  }
  ```

As for the “spaces in names” bit:

- The general syntax for referring to a variable in Bourne shells is: `"$var"` — the `"double quotes"` tell the shell to *expand* any variables inside of them, but to *group* the outcome as a single parameter.
- Omitting the double quotes around `$var` tells the shell to expand the variable, but then *split* the results into parameters (“words”) on whitespace. This is how the shell splits up parameters, normally.
- Using `'single quotes'` causes the shell to *not expand* any contents, but *group* the parameters togethers.
- You *can* use `\` (backslash-blank) to escape a space when you're typing (or in a script), but that's usually harder to read than using `'single quotes'` or `"double quotes"`…

Note that the *expansion* phase includes: `$variables` `wild?cards*` `{grouping,names}with-braces` `$(echo command substitution)` and other effects.

```
                    |   expansion    |   no expansion
      -------------------------------------------------------
        grouping    |     "  "       |    '   '
        splitting   |  (no punc.)    |  (not easily done)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your explanations ! And I will learn more on shell functions then if you think this is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

When you put your script inside `/usr/bin` you can call it anywhere. And to deal with whitespace in the shell just put the target between "" (but this doesn't matter !!).
Well here is a demo:

```
#!/bin/bash

#you can use dirname but that's not apropriate
#shorter=$(dirname $1)
#Use parameter expansion (too much better)
shorter=${1%/*}

echo $shorter
```

Comment: Two things 1) please do not try to parse `ls` like that, it will break in horrific ways. Instead just use the shell's native syntax: `for i in *; do ...; done`  2) Rather than the external call to `dirname`, instead use the parameter expansion `${var%/*}`

Comment: well thanks, but i'm trying to make things more clearer to our newbie friend and 'dirname' is there for some reason!!

Comment: I have no issues with making things more friendly, but using `ls` like that is not making it more friendly, it is **broken code**.  Just try to see what happens if you have a file with a space in its name (which is very common).  `dirname` is there because it predates Parameter Expansion and many people who use the shell don't know it even exists (I know I didn't for quite some time.) It makes the code more efficient as it doesn't cause the shell to fork itself to exec the external binary.

Comment: i agree with you about ls. And thank you for the second information, i didn't have it in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way to do it, since you have `dirname` on your Mac:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$(dirname "$1")"
```

Since you mentioned in the comments that you wanted to be able to drag files into a window and `cd` to them, you might want to make your script allow file *or* directory paths as arguments:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -f "$1" ] && set "$(dirname "$1")"  # convert a file to a directory
cd "$1"
```